# update_option from a pre populated form array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, forms

How can I update_option in WordPress from this:
everything I do seems not to work; I must be missing something simple.

```
$l1teams = array(
    1=>"Caterham-Renault",
    2=>"Ferrari",
    3=>"Force India-Mercedes",
    4=>"HRT-Cosworth",
    5=>"Lotus-Renault",
    6=>"Marussia-Cosworth",
    7=>"Mercedes GP",
    8=>"Mclaren-Mercedes",
    9=>"Red Bull-Renault",
    10=>"Sauber",
    11=>"Toro Rosso-Ferrari",
    12=>"Williams-Renault",
    );

<td><select name="league1_driver1_team"><?php foreach($l1teams as $team){?> <option value="<?php echo $l1d1t ?>"><?php echo $team ?></option> <?php } ?> </select></td>
```

I have all the other code setup correctly; I just cannot insert this value into the database in WordPress and echo it back out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to echo `$l1d1t` in your option tag which seems to be undefined in your example.  You probably want something want to change your code to something like this:

```
<td><select name="league1_driver1_team"><?php foreach($l1teams as $team_id => $team_name){?> <option value="<?php echo $team_id; ?>"><?php echo $team_name; ?></option> <?php } ?> </select></td>
```

Essentially what I am doing is setting the array index to `$team_id` and the array value to `$team_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did have something like that setup first using $key & $value.

Ive changed the code to your example which is essentially the same as i had before i posted.

My question is how can i update the options on the database to hold the value selected in the option when saved.

My update_option code and variable are:

'
$l1d1t = $_POST['league1_driver1_team'];
update_option('league1_driver1_team', $l1d1t);


$l1d1t = get_option('league1_driver1_team');
'

Comment: That code should work.  However take a look at the example in the Codex about `update_option`.  You need to make sure that the option you are trying to update exists already, if not you need to use `add_option`.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: Like I said, you need to add some debug around the update_option() call and see what it is returning.  It returns true on a successful update, false on a failure.

Comment: what i did was:  if ($variable == $key){echo "selected";}
It was infact updating the database, i just was not calling the saved value to the selected field on the <option>